# PowerShell : Cannot find a provider with the name

Tags: powershell, remote-access, wmf

Trying to update existing powershell version(V2) to latest version (V5.) on about 50 remote computers.
Obtained install instructions and script(Install-WMF5.1) from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.1/install-configure 
and script executes successfully on local machine.

Environment is as follows
 - Win 7, Sp1
 - PSRemoting Enabled
 - Powershell is run as admin

When running the below command, I get the following error message. **"Cannot find a provider with the name '"**

Invoke-Command -FilePath \Install-WMF5.1.ps1 -ComputerName comp1

Please assist.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when installing WMF 5.1 to a Server 2008 R2 box. Installing .NET Framework 4.5.2 resolved the issue for me.